# Android SQLite SELECT Query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have taken `String` value from a `EditText` and set it inside `SELECT QUERY after WHERE` condition

As

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
EditTextet2 et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

String name = et.getText().toString();

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE name = '"+name+"'", null); 

c.moveToNext();

tv.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: print name and make sure you are getting valid name. use c.moveToFirst(); instead of C....next() and try.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try trimming the string to make sure there is no extra white space:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE TRIM(name) = '"+name.trim()+"'", null);
```

Also use `c.moveToFirst()` like @thinksteep mentioned.

Comment: This example is very bad and allows for SQL Injections. Why not use the second parameter correctly instead of inserting null?

Answer (score 39):

This is a complete code for select statements.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM table ", null);
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        // Passing values 
        String column1 = c.getString(0);
        String column2 = c.getString(1);
        String column3 = c.getString(2); 
        // Do something Here with values
    } while(c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
db.close();
```

Comment: Please note that using c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("column1")) is better than c.getString(0): you won't have to update indexes if you change your query.

Comment: I would also escape name parameter to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 15):

Try using the following statement:

`Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE name = ?", new String[] {name});`

Android requires that WHERE clauses compare to a ?, and you then specify an equal number of ? in the second parameter of the query (where you currently have null).

And as Nambari mentioned, you should use `c.moveToFirst()` rather than `c.moveToNext()`

Also, could there be quotations in name? That could screw things up as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the below code.

```
String areaTyp = "SELECT " +AREA_TYPE + "  FROM "
            + AREA_TYPE_TABLE + " where `" + TYPE + "`="
            + id;
```

where id is the condition on which result will be displayed.

Comment: This has an SQL Injection  Problem

Answer (score 1):

```
 public User searchUser(String name) {
    User u = new User();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //get the database that was created in this instance
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME_User+" where username =?", new String[]{name});
    if (c.moveToLast()) {
        u.setUsername(c.getString(1));
        u.setEmail(c.getString(1));
        u.setImgUrl(c.getString(2));
        u.setScoreEng(c.getString(3));
        u.setScoreFr(c.getString(4));
        u.setScoreSpan(c.getString(5));
        u.setScoreGer(c.getString(6));
        u.setLevelFr(c.getString(7));
        u.setLevelEng(c.getString(8));
        u.setLevelSpan(c.getString(9));
        u.setLevelGer(c.getString(10));
        return u;

    }else {
        Log.e("error not found", "user can't be found or database empty");
        return u;
    }

}
```

**this is my code to select one user and one only**
so you initiate an empty object of your class then
 you call your writable Database 
use a cursor in case there many and you need one 
here you have a choice Use : 1-

```
   if (c.moveToLast()) { } //it return the last element in that cursor
```

or Use : 2-

```
 if(c.moveToFirst()) {  } //return the first object in the cursor
```

and don't forget in case the database is empty you'll have to deal with that in my case i just return an empty object

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 1):

Detailed answer:

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{name};
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
       "SELECT * FROM " + tabl1 + 
       " WHERE " + name + " = ? ", selectionArgs
    );
```

**selectionArgs  :** this takes the `'name'` you desire to compare with, as argrument.

Here note **"A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry of the table you refer to".**

So,to move to first entry :

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

**getColumnIndex(String ColumnName) :** this returns the zero-based column index for the given column name.

```
tv.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));
```

In case, you want to go searching through multiple rows for a given name under 'name' column then use loop as below:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        ////go traversing through loops
           
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

This should solve the problem.