# Android SQLite - Match multiword string

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-like

I have a row in **mytable** with this value **'{"test":"Hello World"}'** in **column1**.

If I search the database with

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE column1 LIKE '%Hello World%'
```

I get nothing. If I change the query to

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE column1 LIKE '%Hello%'.
```

I get results but this is not what I want because this returns unwanted rows.

Is something wrong with the space character between the two words?

My code looks like this:

```
Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1 LIKE '%Hello World%'",null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //log results
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to this link: [http://thinkdiff.net/mixed/sqlite-space-within-string/](http://thinkdiff.net/mixed/sqlite-space-within-string/) for just information

Comment: Try that query in sqlite browser and see the results are coming or not..

Comment: I already did that and it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

Code like this will skip the first row. Instead, do it like this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        //...
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column1 LIKE '%Hello World%'
```

works for me in SQLite Database Browser (http://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqlite_database_browser_portable).

you can use the trim function as well:

- [Android SQLite SELECT Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280692/android-sqlite-select-query)