# How to show username in MyProfile page by retrieving data from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am doing Android Login application.I done Sqlite connection and done logged in succesfully .If I log in i will be moved to Welcome page.If i click on Profile page,I need to show my Username which is logged in.Please help.

I need in detail,how to call in Activity

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: no one will be able to help you if u do not show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

After successsfull Login.... Get The Username ane Stored in shared prefernce. When ever u will require in any page, Open shrared prefernce and set Username where you want to set..

[Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) refer it

Answer (score 0):

At the time of login, store the email id in shared Preferences.

Now when you go to Profile screen,fetch that stored email id from shared preferences and then make a query to fetch Username for that email id from the database using sqlite.

[This might help you in Select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280692/android-sqlite-select-query)